# Internet Explorer 8 adds line breaks after link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

With the following code, IE 8 adds line breaks after the `link_to`. Its in a `<p>` tag, so there should not be a line break. Even adding a CSS class to the link_to with `display: inline` does not help.

```
<p>After registering, at any time you can click on the "My Profile" links and buttons found throughout the site, or simply click <%= link_to "here", user_path(current_user) %>.</p>
```

Here is the HTML that is generated:

```
<p>After registering, at any time you can click on the "My Profile" links and buttons found throughout the site, or simply click <a href="/users/1">here</a>.</p>
```

[image: IE8 link_to line break]

Comment: Can you post the CSS of both the <p> and <a> elements? I don't see any line-break (<br>) in your code, so it must be a CSS problem.

Comment: Turns out I had an anchor to onpage link without a closing tag. <a name="change_account" />